# Problem while sending a string from client to server in java

Tags: java, string, sockets

I have sent a String from client to server but when it receives to the server it doesn't print in the first time only in second time and don't know why.
Here is the code :
Client Side:

```
String str = "40D32DBBE665";  
while (str != null)   {  
    out.writeUTF(str);  
    }
```

Server Side:

```
String st="";  
while(in.readUTF()!=null){ // it gets into the loop in the first time 
            System.out.println("Test"); // in the first time it prints this line 
            st = in.readUTF();  
            System.out.println(st);  
          }
```

So how I can receive it in the first time. Please help !!!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's really unclear exactly what you mean by "in the first time" etc. A pair of short but complete programs (one server, one client) would really help. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please show more of your code.

Comment: @Jon Skee because the string will be sent multiple times and received multiple times since it is in a loop in the server/client sides.

Comment: In the first piece of code, nothing's ever changing `str` - do it doesn't make sense to be in a loop checking the contents of `str`... as I say, a short but *complete* pair of programs would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(in.readUTF()!=null){ // it gets into the loop in the first time 
            System.out.println("Test"); // in the first time it prints this line 
            st = in.readUTF();
```

should be

```
while((st=in.readUTF())!=null){ // don't miss odd messages
     System.out.println(st);
}
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively reading twice before printing on the server. Try this:

```
  while((st = in.readUTF())!=null){ // it gets into the loop in the first time               
        System.out.println(st);  
      }
```